# Evaluating if pointer's pointer exists for an 'n' value

Tags: c++, pointers

So it was a little difficult phrasing this question in the title.

Basically, I have a class 'Person'.
This person points to a mentor through this function

```
void Person::setMentor(Person* person) {
// bunch of conditions
mentor = person;
}
```

One of my conditions have to be that there can be at maximum 4 levels of person-mentor. So I'd like to check if

```
person->getMentor()
```

exists, and if it does three times over, then the hierarchy is too big and the method will return an error. Any ideas how I do it more elegantly than to write it all in a gigantic line?

Comment: Why do you want to set a limit on number of mentors?   There is nothing in real life limiting ability of someone's mentor to also have a mentor.   It is even possible for the linkage to be circular (e.g. person A is a mentor for B is a mentor for C is a mentor for A).   It would be better to cope with such cases, rather than imposing an arbitrary depth on the linkages.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is basically a linked list, you could iterate and check:

```
int depth;
for (depth = 0; depth < MENTOR_LIMIT; depth++) {
    if ((person = person->getMentor()) == NULL) {
        break;
    }
}
if (depth >= MENTOR_LIMIT) {
    // return error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
Person person;
person.mentor = new Person;
person.mentor->mentor = new Person;
person.mentor->mentor->mentor = new Person;
```

the following code

```
auto countMentors(const Person& person)
{
    std::size_t count = 0;
    for(auto p = &person; p->getMentor() != nullptr; p = p->getMentor())
    {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

will return `3`.